# Relationships are created but not stored in embedded neo4j

Tags: neo4j, relationships

I have a strange problem where I get to create relationships in embedded neo4j using createRelationshipTo() method. But when I use the getRelationships() method to access those relationships, no relationships are found. When I create a relationship and use getRelationships() method immediately, that relationship is found. But later on, that relationship gets lost.

E.g. in the sampleMethod(), I create and retrieve relationships both in the same method so it returns both relationships but when I try to retrieve the same relationships using the same getRelationships() method in sampleMethod2(), it gives nothing.

```
public ArrayList<String> sampleMethod() {
        ArrayList<String>list = new ArrayList<String>();
        DatabaseConnection dbConnection = new DatabaseConnection();
        GraphDatabaseService graphDb = dbConnection.connectToDatabase();
        Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx();

        Node user = graphDb.findNode(Label.label("User"), "userName", "hamna123");
        Node restaurant = graphDb.findNode(Label.label("Restaurants"), "name", "The Grand Regency");
        Relationship rel = user.createRelationshipTo(restaurant, RelationshipType.withName("Visited"));
                    Relationship rel2 = user.createRelationshipTo(restaurant, RelationshipType.withName("Favorite"));
        for (Relationship relationship : user.getRelationships()) {
            String found = relationship.getType().name().toString();
            list.add(found);
        }
        tx.close();
        //graphDb.shutdown();
        return list;

    }

public ArrayList<String> sampleMethod2() {
        ArrayList<String>list = new ArrayList<String>();
        DatabaseConnection dbConnection = new DatabaseConnection();
        GraphDatabaseService graphDb = dbConnection.connectToDatabase();
        Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx();
        Node user = graphDb.findNode(Label.label("User"), "userName", "hamna123");
                Iterable<Relationship> relations = user.getRelationships();
        for (Relationship relationship : relations) {
            String found = relationship.getType().name().toString();
            list.add(found);
        }
        tx.close();
        graphDb.shutdown();
        return list;

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't close a transaction without **commited**  it. Otherwise a rollback is performed.

So :

- use the `catch-with-resource` pattern for closing the transaction
- put the tx as successfull  at the end of your code

Example :

```
try ( Transaction tx = db.beginTx())
{
    Node myNode = db.createNode();
    myNode.setProperty( "name", "my node" );
    tx.success(); // commit the tx
}
```